# django user and custom user class

Tags: python, django

In Django you have some naturally defined User class. My app also has a User class defined (they dont conflict, that's not the question)

My question is, since these two User classes conceptually represent the same thing (well, users) then it would be natural to integrate them. That is, have a single User class that contains all methods and variables of both classes.

What is the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are (at least) two possibilities:

1) Use the ['custom user' functionality of Django (since Django 1.5)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model), or

2) Use a `OneToOneField` to the `django.contrib.auth` `User` from your own user class.

The first allows you to customize more, but you might get some problems if you try to use third-party-apps that are either not ready for custom users or need specific properties of the stock `User`. For example, [Django Guardian](http://django-guardian.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) doesn't work [if you remove the `User`-`Group` relationship.](http://django-guardian.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide/custom-user-model.html)

The second is less intrusive, but doesn't allow you to customize the existing fields of `User`. Also, you need to manually create the instance of your own user class at registration time.

Comment: So I should be doing one of those if I want to use Django's authentication method on my app's users?

Comment: Yes. The first method works directly (if you correctly specify the `USERNAME_FIELD`), and for the second case, all authentication-related fields should be in `auth.User` anyways. If you want to change authentication-related fields, you should use the first method.

Comment: Regarding the issue with 3rd party apps, this should not be an issue if you do it properly... in other words if your custom user model inherits from both `AbstractBaseUser` (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#specifying-a-custom-user-model) and `PermissionsMixin` like Django's one does https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#custom-users-and-permissions

Comment: In other words, option 1 is strongly recommended. You might explore option 2 if you have several kinds of sub-classed user in which case you need the 'object composition' type approach this option provides

Comment: Anenthropic I'm a new user in Django and as I was reading more about it I realized that probably option 1 would be a bit too much for me at the moment. I'll stick to option 2 for now :-) Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should read the documentation about [Extending the existing User model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model).

> If you wish to store information related to User, you can use a one-to-one relationship to a model containing the fields for additional information. This one-to-one model is often called a profile model, as it might store non-auth related information about a site user. For example you might create an Employee *(note: called MyUser below)* model:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class MyUser(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    newfield1 = models.CharField(...)

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'myapp.MyUser'
```

Comment: This is what sk1p said. +1 for explicitely mentioning AUTH_USER_MODEL

Comment: Actually, I was reading more and I think this isn't correct. You either define a OneToOneField from custom users to Django users, OR you make your custom users be Django's users in which case you change AUTH_USER_MODEL but your custom users now have to inherit a bunch of stuff and have a bunch of required variables and methods in order for Django to work properly. Your solution seems to be a half way mix of both.